# Seaborn heatmap, format of annotations in non-diagonal cells

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, plot-annotations

I generated a heatmap using seaborn version 10.1. I would like to format the annotations of each cell with `fmt='.2g'`

However, this seems to only affect the cells on the diagonal.

```
import seaborn as sn

x = np.array([[0.99082, 0.00102, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.98767, 0.00529, 0.00088],
              [0.01744, 0.00097, 0.94961, 0.00291],
              [0.00990, 0.00099, 0.00594, 0.94356]])

sn.heatmap(x, annot=True, fmt='.2g', cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
```

What I get is this:

[image: Seaborn Heatmap with differently formatted annotations]

I have been through the Seaborn documentation, but I couldn't find any setting that applies the formatting to the annotations of the non-diagonal cells. Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

Edit: For example, I would expect 0.017 be formatted as 0.02 and 0.0099 be formatted as 0.01, but 0.00 should be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `fmt='0.2f'`, which comes from [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) notation, to set the format for all annotations

  - [Real Python: A Guide to the Newer Python String Format Techniques](https://realpython.com/python-formatted-output/)
  - [mkaz.blog: Python String Format Cookbook](https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/)
- To change values of `'0.00'` to `'0'`, use the [`matplotlib.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/text_api.html) API.

```py
import seaborn as sns

x = np.array([[0.99082, 0.00102, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.98767, 0.00529, 0.00088],
              [0.01744, 0.00097, 0.94961, 0.00291],
              [0.00990, 0.00099, 0.00594, 0.94356]])

sns.heatmap(x, annot=True, fmt='0.2f', cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

# update the desired text annotations
for text in ax.texts:
    if text.get_text() == '0.00':
        text.set_text('0')
```

[image]

### Reference:

[change certain squares in a seaborn heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707033/change-certain-squares-in-a-seaborn-heatmap)

Comment: Thank you for your solution!